# How to solve "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` " error?

Tags: python, numpy

```
image_dataset = np.array(image_dataset)
mask_dataset =  np.array(mask_dataset)
image_number = random.randint(0, len(image_dataset))
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(image_dataset[image_number], (patch_size, patch_size, 3)))
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(mask_dataset[image_number], (patch_size, patch_size, 3)))
plt.show()
```

It is showing the following error. I have used 3 bands image and the resolution is 10000X10000 I don't know how to solve it.

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16264/3022045018.py in <module>
----> 6 plt.imshow(np.reshape(image_dataset[image_number], (patch_size, patch_size, 3)))
7 plt.subplot(122)
8 plt.imshow(np.reshape(mask_dataset[image_number], (patch_size, patch_size, 3)))
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: `mask_dataset` is almost surrely an empty array, you need to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurred at instruction operating on *image_dataset*.

So probably just this array is empty (not *mask_dataset* as in a comment).

Of course, *mask_dataset* can also be empty, but this may come to light later,
when this instruction gets executed.